# Can't tag new questions using the Android app?

Tags: support, tags, android-app

It seems that when I use the app on an Android phone, it doesn't allow tagging, which is a condition for posting the question. That makes it a bit difficult. Am I the only one experiencing these challenges?

The tags are the biggest issue I guess, as I can't post without tags.

Also are there any functionalities in the app apart from plain writing and cut/paste? Is there no toolbar? I can't seem to find one. And how about HTML/link and the simple `>`, `_` and `**` tags, do they function in the app?

Comment: It's all there, just in different places. It only lack certain actions like deleting.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll explore it more, just good to know it's there so my exploration won't be futile

Comment: @Mr.Concept posted a related (perhaps more detailed) problem description on another meta-site, i.e. [Cannot tag a question using the Android app and therefore cannot post a question](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1797/254)

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly unintuitive, true - but it is possible. You have to search for tags:

[image]

And then you have to *click* on the search results. If you don't click on it, it won't tag the question and you won't be able to post.